# Tag or attribute to disable influence on preceding element's position

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make an interesting bar I saw, Its purpose was to be a frame on the bottom of the browser with many social media links in the form of images to remind the visitor to share however this one was interesting to me because the images did not look like they could be created in the frame because from my experience image's top left has to be in the tag that created it however these were not, they produced from the frame with half the images outside (about 20px frame height and 40 image height).

First I tried by making the frame with its background gradient, limited its height put the images inside it and offsetting the images up - the bar insists on being on the top half of the images.

Next I tried making the gradient in a separate DIV inside another with contains both the images and the background, then offsetting the images down into the bar - Just pushes the bar down.
If it is possible to tell the browser to (through css properties obviously) to not consider the bar's position when coming across the images next, the images should render in the same place, then I don't see any problems offsetting them half up.

[image: How it currently looks, images need to be moved down into the bar.]

Apologies I can't share a JSFiddle as I don't know how to use images there. So heres the code I explained last.

```
div#shareBar div {
    background: rgb(204,204,204);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%, rgb(140,140,140) 16%, rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(204,204,204)), color-stop(16%,rgb(140,140,140)), color-stop(100%,rgb(204,204,204)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 );
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    height: 26px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="shareBar" style="border: 1px solid red;">  
    <img src="Images/facebook.png"/>
    <img src="Images/Twitter.png" />
    <img src="Images/G+.png" />
    <img src="Images/Letter.png" />
    <div></div>
```

The images are 32x32 icons, so if the images where to be in the middle the padding would have to be 10px.

Comment: Actually, I can't totally understand what do you want. Do you want to something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/En6Wk/

Comment: @Edward You got it. I think I see what you did there, but could you write an answer to confirm? Then I'll accept. Could it always be used to do this sort of thing to any elements?

Comment: sorry i don't completely understand what you seek...but that sounds like image sprites, and in particular, used with {clip:} on <img /> elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="socialBar">
    <a href="facebookShare" class="facebook">Facebook</a>
    <a href="twitterShare" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
    <a href="gplusShare" class="gPlus">G+</a>
    <a href="email" class="email">Email</a>
</div>
```

Note no secondary div

**CSS**

```
#socialBar {
    height:48px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 53%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1) 73%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)), color-stop(73%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 53%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1) 73%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 53%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1) 73%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 53%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1) 73%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 53%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 1) 73%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}

#socialBar a
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url(http://cdn.robcubbon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-media-gif.gif);
    /*PLease use your own image preferably one with a trasparent background*/
    text-indent:-999px;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#socialBar a.facebook 
{
    background-position: -96px -32px;
}

#socialBar a.facebook:hover 
{
    background-position: -96px 0;
}

#socialBar a.twitter 
{
    background-position: -128px -32px;
}

#socialBar a.twitter:hover 
{
    background-position: -128px 0;
}

#socialBar a.email 
{
    background-position: -64px -32px;
}

#socialBar a.email:hover 
{
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

#socialBar a.gPlus 
{
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#socialBar a.gPlus:hover 
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b34Gs/

**How It Works**

I used http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to edit you gradient to stop halfway up the bounding `div` which is given a fixed height.

Next I've set up the `a` tags to be `inline-blocks` to be the height and width of the icons. Then the inner text is shifted out of the viewport with `text-indent`.

I have then used [CSS Spriting](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) to give the icons the appropriate background using only one image.

As an added bonus, I've added a simple hover effect, again ussing the sprite, by shifting the background image.

**Update**

So baisically there is no "bar". What there is, is a fairly complicated gradient that is white for the top 50% set as the background of a div. This gives the *appearance* of the link icons being partially embeded in a "bar". This can be demostrated by replacing the gradient with a solid background colour: http://jsfiddle.net/b34Gs/2/.

**Plan B**

In your question, you mention "disabling influence". My above solution does not do this, it provides the illusion of it by manipulating the background gradient. What you are referring to is known as *removing an element from the natural flow of the document*. This is commonly done in two ways: `float:left|right` or `position:absolute;`. As a matter of personal preference, if I can keep elements in their natural flow, I will.

For my following examples the HTML is the same as the above.  I have also restored your original, full-height gradient to `#scocialBar`.

*Floats*

```
#socialBar a
{
    position:relative; //New
    float:left; //New
    top:-16px;  //New
    margin-right:5px; //New
    display:inline-block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url(http://cdn.robcubbon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-media-gif.gif);
    text-indent:-999px;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
```

`position:relative;` performs the function of indicating that offsets are relative to the elements' 'natural' position. `top:-16px;` is indicating that the elements' top edge is offset by 16px. `margin-right:5px;` gives some horizontal spacing to the `<a>` tags.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b34Gs/4/

*Absolute Positioning*

Add `position:relative` to the `#scocialBar` style. This performs the function of indicating that child elements are positioned relative to this element. As we are adding `position:absolute` to the child `<a>` elements we have to explicitly position them as they will default to the top, left corner of their nearest ancestor element with `position:relative`

```
#socialBar a
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-16px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url(http://cdn.robcubbon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-media-gif.gif);
    text-indent:-999px;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}

#socialBar a.facebook 
{
    background-position: -96px -32px;
}


#socialBar a.twitter 
{
    left:50px;
    background-position: -128px -32px;
}

#socialBar a.email 
{
    left: 130px;
    background-position: -64px -32px;
}

#socialBar a.gPlus 
{
    left: 90px;
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b34Gs/1/

**NOTE** I have borrowed the sprites from some one elses website for this example. You whould use your own and makesure that it has a transparent background so the rounded edges are handled better than what the example has.

Comment: I can read how everything works except how the images go outside the bar, what property does that?

Comment: There is no actual bar per-se. There is the `div` all the `a` tags are fully contained within that `div`. The "bar" is the background gradient, coloured in the bottom half, white for the top half. The scocial icons are background images for the `a` tags which are given a height and width. If you use a tool like firebug for firefox, if you inspect the div you will see  everything is fully contained within it

Comment: ...sooo..how does it do what I asked? I can see how everything works except that. Dont tell me that it does.

Comment: I may be confused... does my example achieve the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Absolutely, oh, Thanks for adding an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In particular, it has several solution for positioning. my example used minus margin but also you can use `position`, `background-image`, etc.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="shareBar" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="bar">
        <img src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/twitter-icon.png"/>
        <img src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/facebook-icon.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#shareBar .bar {
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: rgb(204,204,204);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%, rgb(140,140,140) 16%, rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(204,204,204)), color-stop(16%,rgb(140,140,140)), color-stop(100%,rgb(204,204,204)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(204,204,204) 0%,rgb(140,140,140) 16%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 );
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    height: 26px;
}
div#shareBar .bar img {
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on these other methods? I'm not going to accept it if it doesn't answer the question at least.

Comment: @LeeAllan My answer is capable to solving this problem. I can provide some other example but it will be more complicated way.